# Access: Syntax error (missing operator) ONLY on Form_Load

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, expression

i have a list on a form on my Access database.
I also have a button on my form. When i click the button, the RowSource of my list shall Change. 
The code is following:

```
Private Sub Button_Left_Click()
    BR_Organization_String= ""
    For i = 0 To BR_OrganizationList.ListCount - 1
        BR_Organization_String= " " & BR_OrganizationList.Column(1, i) & ", " & BR_Organization_String & " "
    Next i
    BR_Team.RowSource = ("SELECT Teamname FROM Projekt WHERE AbteilungsID IN (" & BR_Organization_String & ")")
End Sub
```

When i click on the "Button_Left", than this code works well, there is no Problem.
But as soon as i Close the Form and open it again, i always get this message:

```
Syntax error (missing Operator) in query Expression 'AbteilungsID IN('.
```

But i don't have anything on my Form_Load, the code of my form load is just empty. So why is Access giving me such a message even when i don't click the "Button_Left"-Button and only open up the form which has no code to procedure on form_load?

I also tried to write this code on the form_load, but it didn't fix the Problem:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    BR_Organization_String = "" 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a string to force a valid expression for the rowsource using either a non-existing or a default AbteilungsID, like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    BR_Organization_String = "0" 
End Sub
```